# Calculating a Random for C++

Tags: c++, random

This is probably a super easy question, but I just wanted to make 10000% sure before I did it.
Basically Im doing a formula for a program, it takes some certain values and does things when them.....etc..

Anyways Lets say I have some values called:

```
N
Links_Retrieved
True_Links
True_Retrieved.
```

I also have a % "scalar" ill call it, for this example lets say the % scalar is 10%.

Links Retrieved is ALWAYS half of N, so that's easy to calculate.
BUT I want True_Links to be ANYWHERE from 1-10% of Links_Retrieved.

Then I want True_Retrieved to be anywhere from The True_Links to 15% of Links_Retrieved.
How would I do this? would it be something like

```
True_Link=(((rand()%(Scalar(10%)-1))+1)/100);
```

?
I would divide by 100 to get the "percent" value IE .1 so it's be anywhere from .01 to .1?

and to do the True_retrieved it'd be

```
True_Retrieved=(rand()%(.15-True_Link))+True_Link;
```

am I doing this correct or am I WAYYYY off?
thanks

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "scaler", i.e. something that scales? Because a "scalar" is a mathematical term for a kind of number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rand()` is a very simple Random Number Generator. The Boost libraries include Boost.Random. In addition to random number generators, Boost.Random provides a set of classes to generate specific distirbutions. It sounds like you would want a distribution that's random between 1% and 10%, i.e. `0.01` and `0.1`. That's done with `boost::random::uniform_real(0.01, 0.1)`.

Comment: Where do you get this library?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use advanced random generator like [Mersenne Twister](http://www.bedaux.net/mtrand/).

Answer (score -1):

rand() produces values between 0.0 and 1.0 inclusive, you have to scale that output to the interval you want. To get a value `fact1` between 0.01 and 0.1 (1%-10%) you'd do:

```
perc1 = (rand()/RAND_MAX)*9.0+1.0; //percentage 1-10 on the 0-100 scale
fact1 = perc1/100.0;  //factor 0.01 - 0.1 on the 0-1 scale
```

to get a value between perc1 and 0.15 you'd do:

```
percrange = (15.0 - perc1);
perc2 = (rand()/RAND_MAX)*percrange + perc1;
fact2 = perc2/100.0;
```

so your values become:

```
True_Links = fact1*Links_Retrieved;
True_Retrieved = fact2*Links_Retrieved;
```

This is sort-of-pseudocode. You should make sure `parc1, perc2, fact1, fact2` and `percrange` are floating point values, and the final multiplications are done in floating point and rounded to integer numbers.

Comment: rand produces *integer* values in the range 0 to `RAND_MAX`, not [0.0, 1.0]

Comment: So wouldn't my code work then? im confused I feel like im seeing conflicting info. Because if I produce an Int value from 1-10, then divide by 100, i would get a perfect percent value (.1,.01,.02,etc..) correct?

Comment: @Mercfh: the code in your question, while not C++ did suggest you're using a reasonable algorithm. When `N <= RAND_MAX`, `rand() modulo N` returns a number in `[0,N-1]`. It's only "reasonable" because outcomes smaller than `RAND_MAX % N` are more common than larger outcomes.

Comment: Whoops, too long since I did much random stuff in c++ apparently. fixed my code (but now you really need to make sure those divisions are double divisions)